# Why does my baby moan every 3-5min during sleeping?

Tags: sleep, newborn

My baby girl is 2 weeks old. She starts making squeaks, moans, yawns during sleeping every 3-5min. She did that as well before, but not as often as these two days. She also gets more difficult to settle and fall asleep these two days. Asks for breast right after feeding.

I realize this might be a growth spurt, but how about the noises she makes every 3-5min? Is that normal as well or does it suggest that she has sleeping problems?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at [these related questions](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newborn+sleep) and their answers.

Answer (score 11):

The noises are perfectly normal.  [Here's](http://www.whattoexpect.com/first-year/newborn-sleep.aspx) a good article that explains what's normal and not for sleeping.  Infant sleep is very different from adult sleep.  Basically, any sounds she makes while awake, she will make while asleep.  The danger signs are when she is breathing rapidly, or looks like she is working really hard to breathe.  However, unlike adults, short pauses in their breathing aren't a cause for concern.

Don't worry, soon you will be freaking out when you don't hear the noises for a while.  As soon as you have parenting figured out, it changes.